# how to satisfy both gcc4.1.2 and gcc 4.7.3

Tags: c++, c, gcc

A project need to compile in both gcc4.1.2(company's server) and gcc 4.7.3+(desktop linux system), and have some problems:
1. gcc 4.1.2 does not have `Wno-unused-result` and `Wno-unused-but-set-variable`. I tried to substitute the latter two with `Wno-unused`, but still generate an ignoring return value of a build-in function error.
2. There's also no `Wno-narrowing` in gcc 4.1.2, is there anything else I can use?
What should I do to make both of them happy?

Comment: Can you just modify the code so the warning goes away in a harmless way?

Comment: Fixing the code sounds like a plan, or upgrading the server to something that is *not* a 7-1/2 year old tool chain. Of course you could pipe the result of `gcc --version` to a config property in your make file and determine which CCFLAGS to use from that, but that gets *messy* quick.

Comment: Do you have access to the makefiles?

Comment: the code related with unused result is to call some build-in functions like read(), write().  @WhozCraig I don't have the permission to upgrade gcc version.  can you tell some details about choose gcc according to gcc versions?  I have access to autoconf.ac and Makefile.am

Comment: Why does it matter if function is built-in or not, if function returns value you should use it, period. Especially with ::read() and ::write() functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you deal with the differences between the two versions in the makefile. You can detect the GCC version and pramatically include the extra warning options if the GCC version supports them. This will help when the company finally moves forward.

Fixing the code is worth doing, but don't then not use the warnings. They're the thing telling you there's a problem in the first place (otherwise you wouldn't have enabled them right?)

Anyway, you can get round the unused warnings to system functions by casting the result to void which the compiler is happy you should ignore:

```
(void)builtin( ... );
```